# Laravel : Method [show] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

When trying to access this URL 'users/login' I got that error, Here is my code :

View users/login.blade.php :

```
<head>Sign in : </head>
<body>
{{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'users')); 

echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo Form::label('username', 'User Name');
    echo Form::text('ausername', null, array('class' => 'form-control'));
echo '</div>';

echo '<div class="form-group">';
    echo Form::label('Password', 'Password');
    echo Form::password('apassword', null, array('class' => 'form-control'));
echo '</div>';

echo Form::submit('Sign in', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary'));

echo Form::close();
?>
</body>
```

Controller Usercontroller.php

```
<?php

class UserController extends BaseController {


    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        return View::make('users.index')
            ->with('users', $users);
    }


    public function create()
    {
        return View::make('users.create');
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $rules = array(
            'username'   => 'required|alpha_dash',
            'password'   => 'required|confirmed',
            'name'       => 'required|regex:/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*$/',
            'email'      => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'country'    => 'required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('users/create')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } else {
            $user = new User;
            $user->username = Input::get('username');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
            $user->name = Input::get('name');
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->country = Input::get('country');
            $user->save();
            // redirect
            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created user!');
            return Redirect::to('users');
            }
    }


    public function login()
    {
        $reflector = new ReflectionClass("UserController");
        $fn = $reflector->getFileName();
        dd($fn);
        return View::make('users.login');   
    }


    public function authen()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username' => Input::get('ausername'), 'password' => Input::get('apassword'))))
        {
            return Redirect::intended('users');
        }   
    }


}
```

and my routes.php

```
<?php
Route::resource('users','UserController');
Route::get('users/login', 'UserController@login');
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

is it a route problem, thank you for the help

Comment: I dont think you need to define that `Route::resource` route since *i believe* its only used for restfull controllers. Or is this a rest app?

Comment: its used to load other views and perform some processing within the controller

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I have experienced the same problem as you. The problem ends up with rearranging the resource code, i.e.

```
Route::get('masterprices/data', 'MasterPriceController@data');
Route::get( 'masterprices/upload', 'MasterPriceController@upload');
Route::post('masterprices/upload', 'MasterPriceController@do_upload');
Route::get('masterprices/{masterprices}/multipledelete', 'MasterPriceController@multipledelete');
Route::resource('masterprices', 'MasterPriceController');
```

It checks the other possible handler, if none it will reach the last line which is resource to handle index page.

Answer (score 15):

This one:

```
Route::resource('users','UserController');
```

defines following routes:

```
| GET|HEAD users               | users.index   | UsersController@index  
| GET|HEAD users/create        | users.create  | UsersController@create 
| POST users                   | users.store   | UsersController@store  
| GET|HEAD users/{users}       | users.show    | UsersController@show   
| GET|HEAD users/{users}/edit  | users.edit    | UsersController@edit   
| PUT users/{users}            | users.update  | UsersController@update 
| PATCH users/{users}          |               | UsersController@update 
| DELETE users/{users}         | users.destroy | UsersController@destroy
```

So URI users/login calls users.show route and that's the problem.

Solution is like Kryten said to remove that route completely, but I suppose you still want to use some of the routes for the resource, like in your controller (create, store, index), so better use this:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController', ['only'=> ['index','create','store']]);
```

Comment: I believe there is a way to rename this routes like `user.index` would be `user.about` how to do so?

Comment: @YousefAltaf you wouldn't do that, just create it explicitly if you need to customize the routes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem list with the `Route::resource` call. By including that statement, you're telling Laravel that you want to use a RESTful controller for paths that start with `users`. This means that when you hit the URL 'users/login', the RESTful controller interprets that as a "show" action for the `user` controller and fails, since there's no `show` method. See http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers for details - the table on that page explains what routes are automatically configured when you implement a resource controller.

The solution is to remove `Route::resource('users','UserController');`.

Comment: but if I remove it I lose other functionnalities where I'm using RESTful controller, (index, create, store ...)

Comment: The documentation gives details on how to implement specific methods for the RESTful controller.

Answer (score 3):

Add the custom route before the resource routes in your routes file.

As per Laravel documentation:

> If it becomes necessary to add additional routes to a resource controller beyond the default resource routes, you should define those routes before your call to Route::resource; otherwise, the routes defined by the resource method may unintentionally take precedence over your supplemental routes:

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is one I just found after reading your question. Define your `::resource` routes **after** any `::get` or `::post` routes. I just tested on 4.2 and it's working (after having the same issue).

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue but it was weird one. In my routes file I had:

```
Route::controller('carts', 'CartsApiController');
```

When I changed it to:

```
Route::controller('cart', 'CartsApiController');
```

Everything was fine and I did not have the error again. I am not sure but seems like some naming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced the same problem but i found it very dumb and silly mistake one use route like this : -

```
Route::get('users/login', ['uses'=>'UserController@login', 'as'=> 'userLogin']);
```

and in your view or controller use route('userLogin');  for route to that particular function in your controller

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if somebody is still having this problem in Laravel 8,this worth for me:

```
Route::resource('tags',TagController::class)->except(['show']);
```