# Method App\Http\Controllers\EspecialidadesController::show does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I don't know why I'm getting the error if I am not trying to access the show function. Gonna post the code of the view, controller, and routes.

**View Code**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Editar Especialidad</h1>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        {{ __('Register') }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <form method="PUT" action="{{ route('especialidades.update', $especialidad) }}">
                            @csrf
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <label for="nombre" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
                                    {{ __('Nombre') }}
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="nombre" type="text" class="form-control @error('nombre') is-invalid @enderror" name="nombre" value="{{ $especialidad->nombre }}" required autocomplete="nombre" autofocus>
                                    @error('nombre')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                                <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        {{ __('Editar') }}
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

**Controller code**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {
    $especialidad = Especialidades::findOrFail($id);
    $especialidad->fill($request->all());
    if($especialidad ->save()) {
        return redirect()->route('especialidades.index');
    } else {
        return redirect()->route('especialidades.update');
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::resource('/especialidades', EspecialidadesController::class);
Route::get('/gestionarMedicos', [PersonaController::class,'mostrarMedicos'])->name('personaMostrarMedicos');
```

This is the full error I get

```
Method App\Http\Controllers\EspecialidadesController::show does not exist.
```

I don't know why it's trying to get to the show method if I'm not calling it.

Rickdenhaan question didn't answered my question because in that question they suggested to change the routes and dunno if that will also solve the problem but the answer I marked as correct fixed the issue and it needed less changes and not change my routes as I wanted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel : Method \[show\] does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943570/laravel-method-show-does-not-exist)

Comment: did you create EspecialidadesController with make:controller EspecialidadesController --resource command?

Comment: @Prospero I created the controller when creating the model but not as a resource

Comment: @rickdenhaan I have read the answer to that question. So are you suggesting to don't use a resource route and make a route for all the different methods of the controller?

Comment: From what I can see @rickdenhaan even when I tell the view to use the update function the controller tries to use the show function instead because if I create a show function that doesnt do anything the error dissapiers. I think its happening what Kryten says in the answer of the question you liked in your first comment but from what I can understand that means I need to a route for each method. Is there a way around it to keep the resource route?

Comment: Thanks for your help to both of you but with Hedayatullah answer I managed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `web.php` try to use this code:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\EspecialidadesController;

Route::resource('especialidades', EspecialidadesController::class);
```

**View Code**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('especialidades.update', $especialidad) }}">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')

</form>
```

**Note**: If you get the same error try to run the below commands:

```
composer dump-autoload

php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: sorry the controller was yeah EspecialidadesController. Also why is necessary to remove the / in the route?

Comment: Now I tested it and it worked, only change I needed was the view code, the post method in the form and the @method(put) inside the form. Thank you for your help @Hedayatullah

Comment: @DiegoUtreras No Problem.